# Максимальная допустимая размерность массива в Java

Tags: java, массивы

Здравствуйте, заинтересовался вопросом: «На сколько большой n-мерный массив можно создавать в java?».

Знаю, что значение инициализации массива ограниченно integer, а именно 2^31 - 1 (конечно подразумеваются только натуральные числа n > 0). А вот какой степени мы можем объявить массив ?

Дабы было понятно приведу пример:

```
long[] a = new long[10];
long[][] a = new long[10][];
long[][]...[] a = new long[10][]...[];
```

Интересуюсь ради любопытства, спасибо.

Comment: не знаю точно, но скорее все столько, на сколько хватит ресурсов компьютера, либо ограниченно long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Спецификация виртуальной машины Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1) устанавливает ограничение размерности не более 255:

> An array type descriptor is valid only if it represents 255 or fewer dimensions.

Соответственно, объявление массива с размерностью 256:

```
int[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] array;
```

вызывает ошибку на стадии компиляции:

```
error: array type has too many dimensions
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] array;
                                 ^
```

Но это ограничение касается только явного объявления типа массива размерности 256. При этом ничего не мешает объявить массив типа `Object` размерности 255 и в качестве элементов вставлять другие многомерные массивы. В этом случае глубина вложенности ничем не ограничена, хотя и обращение по индексу потребует приведения типов.

Такой же вопрос на английском: [Maximum number of dimensions in a Java array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060538/maximum-number-of-dimensions-in-a-java-array)

Comment: У вас ошибка на единицу - вы говорите, что объявляете массив размерности 255, но на самом деле 256. И далее в тексте такая же ошибка.

Comment: @Roman спасибо большое, поправил

Answer (score 2):

В спецификации самого языка ограничения на размерность нет, а вот в Java VM - есть  и равна она 255.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае ограничение будет обусловлено ограничениями виртуальной машины Java - это ограничение по памяти.

Опытным путем я определил, что макcимальный размер массива на моей машине (java 8) это

```
int[] array = new int [Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5];
```

Но нам никто не запрещает обернуть массивы в класс и получить:

```
public class SuperLongArray {

   private static int MASK = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5;

   int[] left = new int [Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5];
   int[] right = new int [Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5];

   public int put(long address, int value) {

      if(address & MASK > 0) {//если значение указателя больше чем максимальное значение, то мы записывает его в левый массив
         int pointer = address - MASK;
         left[address] = value;
      } else {
         right[address] = value;
      }
   }

   public int get(long address) {

      if(address & MASK > 0) {
         int pointer = address - MASK;
         return left[address];
      } else {
         return right[address];
      }
   }
}
```

Теоретически можно продолжать до бесконечности, но для указателя приедтся использовать или сложный класс и попробовать `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getMaxArrayMemory() {
        
    int high = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
    int low = 0;
    int middle;
    int res = 0;
    
    while(low <= high) {
        
        middle = (low + high) / 2;
        
        try {
            
        int[] arr = new int[middle];
        res = middle;
        low = middle + 1;
        
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        
        high = middle - 1;
        
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]